# multitouch support in cgscenegraph

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Of all the canvas libraries I have come across, I have found cgscenegraph as a very new library. I have been using kineticjs and paperjs. I want to try cgscenegraph for my current project. Does cgscenegraph support multi-touch ?
Is there a demo regarding the same. Couldnt find any on theie site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's supported : check this [here](https://github.com/GwennaelBuchet/cgSceneGraph/blob/master/api/v1.4.2/files/src_utils_util.global.js.html)

```
var touch = event;
&#x2F;&#x2F;if multi-touch, get all the positions
if (event.targetTouches) { &#x2F;&#x2F; or changedTouches
var touchPoints = (typeof event.targetTouches !== &#x27;undefined&#x27;) ? event.targetTouches : [event];
for (var i = 0; i &lt; touchPoints.length; i++) {
touch = touchPoints[i];

positions.push(new CGSGPosition((touch.pageX - offsetX) &#x2F; cgsgDisplayRatio.x,
(touch.pageY - offsetY) &#x2F; cgsgDisplayRatio.y));
}
}
```